# Pygame couldnt load picture

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a game and when i try to load the picture it says "Cannot find reference 'load' in 'image.py'"

That's my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0, 0, 0,)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Boat Race')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load('boat.png')

crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: i've already seen that PyCharm gives a warning for this, but no error is raised at execution, is it ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is an error with the PyGame installation, but it will be helpful if you post the traceback error. It seems the code is fine, at least to me.

*This should be a comment, but i don't have enough reputation.*

Comment: if you want to provide some code about this : it could help to add `gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(0,0))` in the loop, just for the test

Answer (score 0):

After like 1 hour of thinking i found that the whole problem was with the PyCharm because when i runned the program only with python the image was load and i was able to display it. Ty for your help.